# IE 11 doesn't send CORS 'POST' request to the web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, cors

In my DEV machine I've got a web application (SharePoint site) and a simple ASP.NET MVC app both in the same instance of IIS. They have different domains (but both use SSL):

- SharePoint web application has a URL like "https://sp-dev.company.com" with a certificate issued by CA of the company.
- MVC web app has just a self-signed certificate and URL like "https://localhost:44303"

SharePoint site's home page has a ScriptEditor web part which merely "injects" JavaScript code on the page that queries the MVC app:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url: requestUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
    },
    success: function (data) {
 ...;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        ...;
    }
});
```

The problem is: when I run this code in IE 11 it hits breakpoints within MVC app (i.e. request actually gets the application) when MVC app runs in IIS Express. But IE 11 seems to block the request, not even letting it out to the application pool, when the MVC app runs in 'real' IIS. And the error that I see in the latter case is

```
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

[image]

What can be the reason? I guess, I tried everything, from adding in web.config elements like

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

to enabling CORS in Startup.Configuration() method like

```
public class Startup
```

{
    private static readonly EsClosureConfiguration EsClosureConfigSection = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(Constants.ESClosureConfigSectionName) as EsClosureConfiguration;

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //// ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

and adding URLs of the sites in different zones in IE. Nothing helps. Maybe I'm digging in a wrong direction?

Comment: Looks like CORS issue, just run the JS code from same domain as that of URL(domain) you are using to send data from ajax code, don't run the JS script from independent HTML file from some xyz directory!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is about authentication when using REST API in JavaScript cross web applications.
Please refer this link it will help you to resolve this issue.
https://blog.kenaro.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/
Also please check in your web.config file whether you have this tag or not "Access-Control-Request-Method"